# asp.NET c# : Code working as a console app but not as a web app

Tags: c#, asp.net, docx4j, ikvm

My basic problem was converting a .docx file to .pdf. The problem would be solved incase I was allowed to use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll, which i am not since the server will not have MS Office installed. So I needed a free/open-source library that would allow me to do so. And i came across docx4j.NET.

http://www.docx4java.org/blog/2014/09/docx-to-pdf-in-c-net/

This worked fine as long as I ran it as a Console App. The following is the concerned code snippet:

```
string fileIN = @"C:\Users\...\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\HRDapp\HRDapp\Letter_Templates\AP.docx";
string fileOUT = @"C:\Users\...\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\HRDapp\HRDapp\Letter_Templates\AP.pdf";

log.Info("Hello from Common Logging");

// Necessary, if slf4j-api and slf4j-NetCommonLogging are separate DLLs
ikvm.runtime.Startup.addBootClassPathAssembly(
    System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(
        typeof(org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder)));

// Configure to find docx4j.properties
// .. add as URL the dir containing docx4j.properties (not the file itself!)
Plutext.PropertiesConfigurator.setDocx4jPropertiesDir(projectDir + @"src\samples\resources\");

java.io.File file = new java.io.File(fileIN);

// OK, do it..
WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(file);

java.io.FileOutputStream fos = new java.io.FileOutputStream(new java.io.File(fileOUT));

org.docx4j.Docx4J.toPDF(wordMLPackage, fos);

fos.close();
```

In case of using this in a Web App, the code runs fine till

```
java.io.File file = new java.io.File(fileIN);
```

and gets stuck at

```
WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(file);
```

Although the file path is correct and works fine in the console app, but there seems something else that I am missing here. The log also prints upto the following statement-

iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : [INFO]  org.docx4j.jaxb.Context - Using Java 6/7 JAXB implementation

.. and stops. Any kind of reply directing me to the source of the error will be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the paths don't get all mixed up ? maybe permissions?

Comment: What does "code gets stuck" mean?

Comment: use a try and catch and log any exception you may receive

Comment: See https://github.com/plutext/docx4j.NET/issues/1

Comment: First of all thanks everyone for the quick reply..
@ArturPeniche : Yes.. the paths are exactly as they are in the working console app.. infact the whole code is copied.. so don't think that there might be a path mixup issue..

Comment: @VsevolodGolovanov : I had actually kept flags to be printed at the log after each statement. And observed that the log printed after the "java.io.File ..." line, but didnot print after the next. So I beleive either some error occured or the server crashed.

Comment: @esskar : Yes.. this code snippet is actually inside a try block.. Unfortunately it doesnot return any exception! since there are log statements inside catch which donot get executed..

Comment: just to be clear : there are no error message printed on the browser. The request sent to the server never comes back with a response, and the page tries to load indefinitely..

Answer (score 1):

As Jeroen (of IKVM fame) has explained, when there is no main assembly (eg in an ASP.NET application), the IKVM class loader can't find your assembly when the code is trying to dynamically load a class.

So you'll want to add not just:

```
    ikvm.runtime.Startup.addBootClassPathAssembly(
        System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(
            typeof(org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder)));
```

but also:

```
    ikvm.runtime.Startup.addBootClassPathAssembly(
        System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(
            typeof(org.slf4j.LoggerFactory)));

    ikvm.runtime.Startup.addBootClassPathAssembly(
        System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(
            typeof(org.docx4j.jaxb.Context)));
```